# Visual C++ - Successful build but exe file is not created

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I am using **Visual Studio Community 2017 (C++)** with default configuration on **Windows 10 (64 bit)**.
I have a single CPP file and I am trying to compile it.
The problem is that the "build" works fine, it says success, but the expected exe file is just not created.

I spent a few hours now trying all the available options - release/debug, 64bit/32bit, empty project/console app and many settings changes as was advised on various forums - no luck.

Does anybody know what could be the problem? I just can't find a solution for this.

Comment: Where are you looking for the executable?

Comment: What happens if you try to debug or run the executable from within Visual Studio (normally F5)?

Comment: @NeilButterworth Docs/Visual/Projs...

Comment: @Angew, it says no file found. :(

Comment: Did you look in your project's Debug subdirectory?

Comment: Run with verbose logging, it should specify the full path to the executable somewhere. Or the reason why it doesn't create one, if that is really what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

I found my executable in my projects folder called "Release" (for x32) and "x64/Release".

Although I didn't see them either the first time going through the folders looking for it.

Alternatively I found this site with standalone build tools:
http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

ps: for the pros, I am still a big noob, so I can't tell if that site and tools is of going to be of any use, or even right, to the person asking the question. 
So atleast I have added it and is for him/her to decide if so. ;p

regards,
E Karaagacli